Why Would a Kohen Create Pigul? Weaponization?
One who eats Pigul is Chayav Karet (see Zevachim, Mishna 2:2). There are several ways to create Pigul, but a simple case is such: Priest A is receiving the blood of a sacrificial animal, and he thinks about eating the meat of the same animal beyond its allotted time. One must discontinue the sacrificial service. But if the service is continued and certain conditions come true and the blood is sprinkled ... anyone who eats the meat of that sacrifice, even within the permitted time, receives Karet. Kohanim, however, are presumably scrupulous in their activities. Why would a Kohen do this?
In fact, the Mishna in Gitin 5:4 states:
הַכֹּהֲנִים שֶׁפִּגְּלוּ בַמִּקְדָּשׁ מְזִידִין, חַיָּבִין.Kohanim who intentionally create Pigul in the Temple are liable (for monetary damages to the owner of the sacrifice).
The Yachin/Tiferet Yisrael states:
מזידין
שידע שמזיקו בזה:
Intentionally (means) that he knew he would harm/ruin (the property of another via) this (act)
The Yachin goes on to say:
ונ״ל דלהכי לא נקיט ה״נ שוגגין פטורים, מדאינו מצוי שלא ידע הכהן שמפסיד הקרבן כשיפגלו ויהיה שוגג, דהרי למד דיני קרבן ה׳ שנים קודם שנכנס לעבודה. It appears to me that the reason that (the Mishna) did not similarly state (if Kohanim created Pigul)"by accident they are not liable", is because it is not common for a Kohen not to know that he ruins the sacrifice/property when he does Pigul (the case of accident does not normatively exist) for a Kohen studies the laws of sacrifices five years before initiating his service.
Thus, it is clear that accidental Pigul is a misnomer and not part of the discussion; Kohanim knew about the ramifications and consequences of their sacrificial actions. What is the motive? A Kohen weaponizing a sacrifice - intentionally, on occasion, to thwart the penitence of another?
The weaponization theory is not that far-fetched:
בן ידיד הלכות גניבה פרק ב הלכה א
כהנים שפגלו במקדש לחבירו הוא שהזיק כדי שיביא אחר או שלא יעשה רצונו שלא הביא דורון. Ben Ydid Laws of Theft, 2:1 - Kohanim who create Pigul in the Temple, he has harmed his friend in order to (force him) to bring another (sacrifice) or so that (God) not do his (friend's) will because he did not bring a gift.

He doesn't want to share the meat with others to be able to finish on time?

What makes you think this would be done purposely?

"mm this will be great in the cholent for Shabbos... Oh wait it's Thursday!"  Does that make it pigul?

Maybe a Kohen would not create pigul and the point of the law is to show the holiness of sacrifices to the extent that even such a thought could invalidate the offering?

It could become piggul if the kohein has preference for some part, such as liver or tongue, which he saves for dessert, but stumbles with eating the long order of many other less preferable parts coming afterwards.

Because he is a Saducee and wants to thumb his nose at the rabbis.

It is difficult, if not impossible, to infer any motive from the actual Kohanim from that time. And I couldn't think of a description somewhere where Pigul has actually occurred, and than explained why it had occurred. We are left to infer.
The Mishnah presents a scenario where a priest, who is ideally highly scrupulous, introduces an improper intent that could invalidate an entire sacrifice. Because Pigul requires intent we can rule out that the laws of Pigul is used to cover for any mistakes, or 'young trainee'-situations. Zevachim doesn’t elaborate much on why a Kohen might intentionally think improper thoughts during the sacrificial service, leaving us to wonder whether it was:

A rare but real occurrence that needed a legal framework,
More of a theoretical construct to safeguard the sanctity of the Temple rituals, or
Addressing concerns about potential spiritual negligence or internal conflicts among even our most dedicated people.

As mentioned in the comments by @Double_AA, even a momentary lapse in judgement for whatever personal reasons could create a situation of pigul; and the Mishna seems to (pre-emptively?) provide a legal framework for handling this for whenever it would occur.
Without any known anecdotes we are left to imagine scenarios where even a Kohen Gadol would suffer a momentary lapse in judgement or succumb to a spiritual struggle, or chas weshalom act out of malicious intent.

Please see my edited question - intentional Pigul (knowing full well that this thought or act ruins the sacrifice) is the Pigul norm.
